# Liferay Theme: get Portlet Window State

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-6.2

I'm building a freemarker theme for my liferay 6.2 and I'm struggeling with getting the window state of the login portlet when I'm trying to access a page without the needed permissions. In this case liferay "intercepts" the requests and renders a login portlet on top of my home layout template in maximized window state (which is a good behavior).

My problem is that my home layout looks different from my other layout templates. So the portlet is rendered with the wrong look and feel.

Is there a way to check if the login portlet is rendered or not and if it is get the viewmode to check if I want to render my home layout or not?

This is my code for home layout checks so far. The Todo-Comment is where I'm struggeling.

```
<#-- Check whether layout template of current page is home layout. -->
<#assign isHomeLayout = false />
<#if themeDisplay.getLayout().getTypeSettingsProperty("layout-template-id") == "novofleet-home-layout">
    <#-- TODO: CHECK FOR LOGIN PORTLET AND WINDOW STATE AND RETURN FALSE IF PORTLET IS RENDERED AS MAXIMIZED -->
    <#assign isHomeLayout = true />
</#if>
```

Comment: Would it be enough to find out, if any portlet is maximized on the page, or are you only interested in the login portlet? For example the search portlet could be maximized as well, even if you don't offer an explicit "maximize" button in you look and feel.

Comment: I settled for exactly that. See post update.

Comment: I've extracted your solution and moved it to an explicit answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Answer extracted from the question)*

I just checked whether there is any portlet in maximized window state via Liferay's url params. New code:

```
<#-- Check whether layout template of current page is home layout. -->
<#assign isHomeLayout = false />
<#if themeDisplay.getLayout().getTypeSettingsProperty("layout-template-id") == "novofleet-home-layout">
    <#assign isHomeLayout = true />

    <#-- Check for existence of url parameter which forces portlets to maximezed window state and revoke home layout -->
    <#assign maximized = request.getParameter("p_p_state")!"defaultValue" />
    <#if maximized == "maximized">
        <#assign isHomeLayout = false />
    </#if>
</#if>
```